# Getting line breaks in textContent - puppeteer nodejs

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to get the specific `textContent` from an XPath, but when I get the `textContent` it returns the string, but without the line breaks or any notation of them. Since it's html, I'd expect to get a `<br>` as seen in the html element (description of [this steam page](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=3071606533)) of what I am getting, but it does not return any of the line breaks.

I tried this:

```js
const [e3] = await page.$x('//*[@id="highlightContent"]');
const desc = await e3.getProperty('textContent');
const rawDesc = await desc.jsonValue();
```

This gets the correct string, but it does not get the line breaks, as seen here

```
69420,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0_- The Model T is faster- The budget is <I>NICE</I>- You can use unlimited steel and springsBUT- Two Loops
```

The italic html elements are there, but not the line breaks.

Comment: `textContent` gives you the containing __text__, which does not contain any html tags. You probably want `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem. I think its funny that it gives me the `<>` for the linebreak but then for the italics it gives me the fun `&lt;I&gt;` stuff

Comment: It gives you exactly whats in the DOM. You're getting `&lt;i&gt;` rather than `<i>` because this is _not an italic html tag_, its just text.

Comment: Generally in web scraping, you don't use `.innerHTML` much. Most scrapes are about extracting raw text, without markup, and doing that usually requires drilling all the way down to leaf nodes. What are you trying to do here, exactly?